NX run-many function blocks building of some projects when using the 'watch' flag
I am working in an Angular environment in conjunction with NX. I have the following script in my package.json to build the project:
"start:all": "nx run-many --target=build --projects=\"proj1,proj2,proj3,proj4\" --watch --skip-nx-cache"

Upon running this, it will run proj2:build --watch and then begin watching the project. It doesn't begin building the other 3 projects in this situation.
I understand that NX has their watch function. I am unsure if there is a better way I could be completing this task in that way, but it seemed much slower / doesn't seem to cache results.


I tried adding --parallel and --maxParallel=100, that did not fix.

I tried removing the --watch flag. This allowed for all projects to build, but I need watch functionality.

Here is the weirdest part. I tried removing the project it was getting stuck on, and it said


Running target build for 3 projects and 1 task they depend on:

And then still built the one I had removed (The other dependencies depend on it), correctly built 2 other projects, but left one other project un-built.

I'm assuming there is something that needs fixed in how these depend on each other in some way or I need to fix how they run in parallel to each other.
Any information helps, thanks!

I was able to cut it down to 2 projects that depend on the other 2 projects:
"start:all": "nx run-many --target=build --projects=\"proj1,proj3\" --watch",
This is so close, it builds all 4 projects, but only watches the 2 that were specified

Solution:
In each project.json, under the "build" section, add the following:
"dependsOn": [
   { "dependencies": false, "target": "build"}
],

In nx.json in "taskRunnerOptions" -> "default" -> "options", add:
"parallel": 100

Reasoning:
This took a bit of searching through documentation, but the solution ultimately required 2 things:

The parallel value must be high enough.
Any projects that depend on other projects must not wait for their build to complete.

The issue was that proj1 and proj2 depended on proj3 and proj4, and were by default waiting for their build function to complete. However, because their build call had the --watch flag, it wasn't able to complete the build call, and that dependsOn was never fulfilled.
Setting "dependencies": false in the "dependsOn" allows build to be called without awaiting dependencies to build
Source: https://nx.dev/reference/project-configuration#examples

Also note that you may need to switch to ESBuild as a builder:
https://angular.dev/tools/cli/build-system-migration
